# 'At' or 'On' "a large scale"

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

> There had to be some way to automate this process on a large scale.
>
> There had to be some way to automate this process at a large scale.

Which of these sentences is grammatically correct, and, if both are, preferred or standard in American English?

Comment: Both of them.....

Comment: I say "on a large scale".

Comment: I'd probably use "on" for scale and "at" for level.

Comment: I think 'on' should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. However, "on a large scale" (and "on a scale" in general) is a set phrase. There may be variations in local dialects, but to most English speakers, "at a large scale" would sound slightly awkward.

Checking COCAE (https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), "on a large scale" is used 25x more than "at a large scale".

Google Books ngrams also shows that use of "on a large scale" is much more prevalent:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both are technically grammatically correct sentences, but "on a large scale" sounds more correct with respect to the common usage of this phrase.

Answer (score -1):

"On" sounds correct for American English.

But I think rephrasing the sentence would make the most sense-- "There has to be some way to automate and scale up this process."